# No sound after windows 10 update due to bad driver - how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

Good day,

My Windows 10 desktop yesterday rebooted to install updates. After it came back up, there was no sound at all, and the sound icon in the notification tray shows a red x.

I've tried using the Windows troubleshooter to no avail (it keeps telling me to reboot but the problem persists) and I tried going back to the HP site to download drivers for my specific machine, but that doesn't resolve the problem either. (I'm not even sure that the HP driver installation completes successfully).

I checked the Event Viewer and I'm seeing the errors with "High Definition Audio Controller" and this same device also has the yellow mark in Device Manager. I don't think it's a hardware issue because when I reboot the PC and start back up while disabling signed driver verification, the sound works as normal.

So, somehow Windows updated the driver to something invalid and I don't know how to resolve the problem. At best, I can work around it by continuing to disable signed driver verification.

So, does anyone have any ideas of how I can resolve my problem properly? (i.e. remove the faulty driver and install the proper one)

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of Device Manager and the properties of the device in question (all associated tabs).

Comment: I eventually gave up and did a Windows reset.  That seemed to resolve my problem (even though, as far as I can tell,  the reset left the existing drivers in place - at least, my GPU driver was up to date after the reset).